# Powershell and string output

Tags: powershell

I would like to get a specific content of a file as a string. In my example my expected value would be the "version number" of the powershellscript sicherung.ps1  My code is

```
#Variablen benennen
$file = "C:\Datensicherung\sicherung.ps1"

$text1 = get-content $file -totalcount 5 | select-string -pattern "Version\p{L}5" -quiet
$text1 | write-host
```

I got always a 'true'. How can I make it to provide the found string?

Thanks a lot

Dieter

Comment: Don't use `-Quiet`. Quiet parameter return a boolean instead of a match. As per [the doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Yes, perfect. If you have another hint to the output. I got now a complete line, but I would like to find the string 'version' plus the next 5 characters.